# How to insert a double quotes in a variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, double-quotes

I am trying to send a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email=".$email." LIMIT 1";
echo $sql; //to control
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

When I do that, it returns me:

> SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email=xxx@gmail.com LIMIT 1
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com LIMIT 1' at line 1

Then I tried to run this line in mysql web interface. I copy-paste this:

```
SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email=xxx@gmail.com LIMIT 1
```

It gave me the same error msg. Then I added double quotes before and after email adress:

```
SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email="xxx@gmail.com" LIMIT 1
```

Now, it runs... in the interface. I want this in my php file but I have no idea how to create a variable that capable includes double quotes.

Or is there any other way?

Comment: Don't. Please google: Why should I not use mysql_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add single quotes to your string which will do what you need:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email='".$email."' LIMIT 1";
```

But, if you *really* want double quotes, just escape them:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email=\"".$email."\" LIMIT 1";
```

Or, alternatively, don't concatenation:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM loto_users WHERE email='{$email}' LIMIT 1";
```